# Access to getString() in android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, resources, android-fragments, android-context

In a class extending `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`, is there any way to get access to the `Context.getString(..)` method without the extending class being an inner class of an activity or passing in some context from the outside?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 9):

From a fragment use :

```
 getActivity().getString(...)
```

From an adapter use :

```
 getContext().getResources().getString(...)
```

Yes, you need a context to access the resources.

Comment: Note that `getActivity()` will be null until `onActivityCreated()` is invoked.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I am in a FragmentPagerAdapter, not a Fragment!

Comment: use getContext() so, and if you don't have access to a context, pass it.

Comment: Yes, just pass the context where you need it.

Answer (score 6):

From an Activity, use:

```
this.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

From a Fragment, use:

```
getActivity.getString(R.string.string_name);
```

From an adapter, use:

```
getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.string_name);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue.  From a drawer layout, I wanted to decide which fragment to use in a method called from a helper class.

So in onCreateView...

```
String form = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array)[i];
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        FragmentHelper fh = new FragmentHelper();
        int myFragment = fh.getCurrentFragment(form,context);
```

And in public FragmentHelper()...

```
    public int getCurrentFragment(String form, Context context){
              ...
              context.getResources().getString(R.string.label_item1);
              ...
    }
```

The trick being to add context in front of getResources().  Otherwise, my stack showed that the fragment was not attached to an activity.

Hope this helps someone.