# Unknown class R.string ... when extracting string resource

Tags: android, string

I am trying to extract a string resource out of my activity but get the following error  -

[image: error]

I don't remmber in the past that there was anything that I should have filled before the dot of the "getString" method for extracting a string out of an activity. What am I missing?

Comment: String from another activity or string from the string resource file?

Comment: from the resource file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
String myValue = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

but [`getResources()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) is a method of the `Context` class.

It means that you **can't** do this:

```
private static String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.myurl); //it DOESN'T work!!
```

You can use your `BuildConfig` class to set these kind of values.
Also in your `build.gradle` file you can config them:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
      //..
      buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "....")
    }
    //....
}
```

It will populate `BuildConfig.BASE_URL`.

Comment: I have tried your solution and here is my line of code - '    public String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.hero_apps_api); ' but still getting a NPE. What am I missing? I am declaring the variable before onCreate, if it matters.

Comment: alright, answered to myself. I need to put it inside the lifecycle. Thanks! works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use another constant declared in another activity make sure that is declared public and import it.

If you wand to use a string declared in the string resource file:

```
    getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Comment: your solution gives the following error - 'NPE - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference'

Comment: If you are getting it from the resource file you don't need to assign it to a constant. Retrieve it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `getResources()` like this:

**Java**

```
String yourString = getResources().getString(R.string.herro_app_aoi);
```

**kotlin**

```
val yourString = resources.getString(R.string.herro_app_aoi)
```

Comment: your solution gives the following error - 'NPE - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference'

Comment: I was sure that you are using activity. Are you using a fragment ? if so check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112628/access-to-getstring-in-android-support-v4-app-fragmentpageradapter)

Comment: I am using a string from the resouce file and when trying your method I got the NPE I posted to your comment

Comment: I am using an activity

Comment: My code works fine for me, have you checked [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)