# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.app.Activity.getResources()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting Error while doing this

this is my code

```
String[] options = {getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.capture_video),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel)};
```

This is in Fragment class

Comment: You try to access `getActivity()` before attaching your `fragment` to `activity`. Try to initialize it inside `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112628/access-to-getstring-in-android-support-v4-app-fragmentpageradapter

Comment: Can you tell me how to initialize from onCreate()?

Comment: This is my code what I ma trying to do                                                                         Context context;                                                                                                           protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();}                                                                            String[] options = {context.getString(R.string.capture_video)}

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Initialize your option variable in `onViewCreated()` method of fragment

```
String[] options;

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        options = new String[]{getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.capture_video), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel)};
        Log.e("option",options[0]);
    }
```

above code will solve your problem.